# Add New Local User Without "User must change password at next logon"

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

I am assisting with computers for a small private school.  On each computer, I've created an admin account and a student account.  The latter has almost no permissions to do anything.  We lend these computers out to students when they need a computer to use for homework purposes, and I'm trying to figure out a way to quickly delete this account, then add it back in so it's just a clean install of that account with none of the previous user's history in it.  I found I can delete the account in Powershell with:

```
Remove-LocalUser -Name "Student"
```

I've also found I can add the user with:

```
New-LocalUser -Name "Student" -NoPassword -UserMayNotChangePassword
```

I do not want this account to have a password on it, but I also do not want the user to put a password on it.  But when I create it, the "User must change password at next logon" box is checked.  I don't see a switch to uncheck that, and am curious if someone might know how to make that happen.

Also, if it helps, we're using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old method is a way :) (be aware that WinNT moniker is case sensitive, so do not type it 'winnt' or whatever way)

```
New-LocalUser "Student" -NoPassword  -UserMayNotChangePassword

# WinNT://. is for localhost, use WinNT://MyComp for remote computer
$locUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://./Student,User
$locUser.PasswordExpired = 0
$locUser.SetInfo()

# Optional, but by default passwords expire after 42 days,
# it can be done with WinNT, but easier to read like this
Set-LocalUser "Student" -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1)

```
New-LocalUser  
   [-AccountExpires <DateTime>]
   [-AccountNeverExpires]  
   [-Description <String>]  
   [-Disabled]  
   [-FullName <String>]  
   [-Name] <String>  
   -Password <SecureString>  
   [-PasswordNeverExpires]  
   [-UserMayNotChangePassword]  
   [-WhatIf]  
   [-Confirm]  
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

This should work

```
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
New-LocalUser -Name "Test" -Password $password -UserMayNotChangePassword -PasswordNeverExpires
```

I guess, since it does not have a password, it must ask the user for it.

If the reson for "no password" policy is "simplicity for the user," look at autologin.

Comment: You are right then hit enter directily in  Read-Host without typing something else, but this will stop if it is inside a script

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
New-LocalUser -Name "Student" -NoPassword -UserMayNotChangePassword | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $false
```

Comment: "User must change password at next logon" box will not be disable with this.